# Ember CLI build index.html outside assets folder

Tags: express, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an express.js application that uses ember on the front-end. Currently, my structure is:

```
+ client/
| + ember-app
+ server/
    + express.js
    + public/
    | + assets/
    + views/
    | + index.ejs
```

I've gotten my Ember app to build into the public folder under the express app and I can even change the name if I like but I can't seem to get to change the destination of just the index.ejs to go under the views folder.

So far this is all the documentation I can find on changing the name and destination. [Ember-Cli User Guide](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#configuring-output-paths)

Comment: Are you open to adding a gulp task to call `ember build` and afterward to copy or move `index.ejs` to the views folder?

Comment: It looks like that may be the only resolution here. I was looking for an Ember way instead or introducing gulp (or any other build tool) to the build process. Thanks @PaulOliver

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for ember-cli: https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#configuring-output-paths

In your `ember-cli-build.js` file you can change the destination of most of the generated files:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    app: {
      html: 'index.html',
      css: {
        'app': '/assets/application-name.css'
      },
      js: '/assets/application-name.js'
    },
    vendor: {
      css: '/assets/vendor.css',
      js: '/assets/vendor.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Change the `app.html` is where you will have to experiment.

Comment: Thanks @mattmcmanus,

But I've read the link you have here and even linked to it in my question. 

The problem is when I want my HTML file to be output outside of the public folder and into my views folder.